# How get char keycode when user start typing on keyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

Swift, Swift2 iOS
I have simple project for test only. In this project i have a input text as UITextField and UILabel. If i write code like below:

```
@IBAction func textChange(sender: UITextField) {
    textPreview.text = textEdit.text
}
```

so it is simple i see on Label what someone type on keyboard. But i would like get char as key code e.g. a=65 and when i start write something i need to see key code in Label.

Is any way to capture pressed key and put this info to label?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
@IBAction func textChange(sender: UITextField) {
    let inputStr = textEdit.text
    let charVal = inputStr.characterAtIndex(0)
    textPreview.text = charVal
}
```

Comment: was some errors i tried  `print(textEdit.text?.characters.last)` but i can't capture Enter or Delete